# How do we translate Daniel 9:26?

Tags: prophecy, messiah, daniel

Why do so many of the Bible versions translate Daniel 9:26 as "the Messiah" or "Messiah" when instead the more literal translation seems to be "a messiah"?

King James Bible

> And after threescore and two weeks shall **Messiah** be cut off, but not for himself: and the people of the prince that shall come shall destroy the city and the sanctuary; and the end thereof shall be with a flood, and unto the end of the war desolations are determined.

New American Standard Bible

> Then after the sixty-two weeks, **the Messiah** will be cut off and have nothing, and the people of the prince who is to come will destroy the city and the sanctuary. And its end will come with a flood; even to the end there will be war; desolations are determined.

Comment: There is no article in the [original Hebrew](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/daniel/9-26.htm) Therefore 'Messiah' is correct and 'the Messiah' is wrong. Trying to add the English 'a', the so-called 'indefinite article', is (in my view) always a mistake conceptually. Hebrew has no such thing and nor does Greek and that ought to be a lesson to those of us to whom English is our first language. Hebrew and Greek both have _the article_. It is neither 'definite' nor 'indefinite''. It is _locative_ being associated with the demonstrative pronoun (this, that, these, those).

Comment: The grammatical rules covering the use of definite and indefinite articles in English are very different from Greek and Hebrew.  The latter two languages do not have an indefinite article.  Further, the lack of a definite article do NOT imply the indefinite article.

Comment: @NigelJ Why then do we capitalize it?

Comment: We capitalize it because it is a title : such as King, Earl, President, Prime Minister, Mayor, Apostle, Minister etc etc.

Comment: On the subject of both titles and articles, see [Peter Masters](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/425829/259840) in regard to 'I am King' being a stronger statement than either 'I am a King' (very weak) or 'I am the King'. [Acquisition of the zero and null articles in English](https://escholarship.org/uc/item/2kb4p9r0). It can be argued that 'Messiah etc etc' is a stronger statement than 'the Messiah etc etc'. (Question up-voted +1.)

Comment: @NigelJ Thank You.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An anointed one vs The anointed one?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/81478/an-anointed-one-vs-the-anointed-one)

Comment: The difference is due to the differing interpretation, bec some interpret the person as the high priest rather than the Messiah, in that case "an anointed" or "a Christ" is better. See Cambridge Bible commentary, and various topics on this passage https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/search?q=daniel+9+prince

Answer (score 1):

**Messiah** The grammatical reasons are established.  But beyond those, the translators are taking into consideration the historical fulfilments of the chapter 9 prophesies. "The Anointed One" (NIV) was seen to be the Jewish Messiah who arrived in the first century because this fit the "Time period" of the Seventy Weeks mentioned in this chapter.  Hence the "capital M."

This Anointed One, (Messiah) was *cut off* after 3 and 1/2 years (crucified) just as chapter 9 declared. (Matthew 27:32-44). And just before the crucifixion, this Anointed One (Messiah) made a *Covenant with the Many*. (Daniel 9:27, Mark 14:24) So the translators felt justified in applying these Daniel prophecies to Jesus, the Messiah, and therefore, in using a capital "M."

Comment: Thank You. I understand now.